# Find a unique solution to the following Dirichlet problem.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, boundary-value-problem

I want to show that the following Dirichlet problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0 &  \text{in } \Omega,\\
u = g & \text{on }\partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\Omega = (0,1)^2$ and $g(x, y) = 4xy - 7e^x$, has a unique solution.

I clearly only have to show the existence as uniqueness is given by the maximum principle. In my functional analysis course, we've seen that such a problem admits a solution if and only if each point of the boundary admits a *barrier*, i.e.
$$\forall (x_0, y_0) \in \partial \Omega, \quad \exists w \in C(\bar\Omega) ~~\text{with }~ w(x_0, y_0) = 0~~ \text{and}~~ w > 0 ~~ \text{on }~\bar\Omega\backslash \{x_0, y_0\},$$
and $w$ is superharmonic. Therefore I have to find $w$ defined on the square $\Omega$ that satisfies the above conditions. The only functions I can think of have the form
$$w(x, y) = |x - x_0| + |y - y_0|$$
but it doesn't seem to be superharmonic.. Any help ?

Comment: $1-x^2-y^2$ works for $(1,1)$. You may try the rest....

Comment: Poincare’s criterion (or the exterior sphere condition) applies. So there is a barrier at every point on the boundary.